# woocommerce multilingual - add to cart is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommere multilingual plugin, but add to cart functionality does not work.

Can anyone please suggest work-around ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I came across the same issue. I just tried the different solutions they gave on this page.
[Help link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-cart-brokennot-adding-products). There are to many to post here so I am rather giving you the thread

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, I will check the link.

Comment: If I disable this plugin, everything seems to be working fine. so, it must be an issue with this plugin, I tried the solutions from the post you sent, but, they didn't work. can you please suggest how you resolved this issue ?

Comment: After I repaired my database my issue were of the past. Which plugin are you using for your multilingual? Maybe we used different plugins and actually had a different issue.

Comment: I am using woocommerce multilingual plugin.